# Find the generating function for the recurrence:

Tags: generating-functions

Struggling to approach keep ending with solutions that do not work.

Find the generating function for the recurrence:

$$a_{+1}= \frac{a_}3 + 1, \quad ≥ 0$$

with the initial condition $a_0 =0$.

Comment: This will be closed if you show no effort. You didn't even type the question, only used a camera.

Comment: Sorry about that coffeemath, was trying to enter the characters on my keyboard but was having trouble

Comment: So what did you try specifically?

Comment: 1) went in using the examples from https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Combinatorics_and_Discrete_Mathematics/Applied_Combinatorics_(Keller_and_Trotter)/09%3A_Recurrence_Equations/9.06%3A_Using_generating_functions_to_solve_recurrences but wasn't computing well since the +1 term, I know 1,1,1,1 = 1/(1-x) but I wasn't getting correct final answers

Comment: 2) I went in trying to manipulate the sums, from f(x)= 3a0+ 3Sum (an+1) x^(n+1) - (1/x-1) but I resulted in f(x) = -2x^2/ (1-x)(1-3x) which doesn't work

Comment: I know I'm overlooking something here but I've just been stumped on this question all day

Comment: For future reference, the details you've added in comments should have been added to the body of your question

Comment: Thanks User170231, really appreciate the guidance, I'll make sure to do that moving forward!

Answer (score 1):

Let $A(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge0}a_nx^n$ be the generating function for the sequence $\{a_n\}$. For $|x|<1$, we can multiply both sides by $x^n$ and sum over $n\ge0$ to get

$$\sum_{n\ge0} a_{n+1} x^n = \sum_{n\ge0} \left(\frac13 a_n + 1\right) x^n$$

Now we can recover a few instances of $A(x)$,

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\ge1} a_n x^{n-1} &= \frac13 A(x) + \sum_{n\ge0}x^n \\
\implies \frac{A(x) - a_0x^0}x &= \frac13 A(x) + \frac1{1-x}
\end{align*}$$

and from here you can easily solve for $A(x)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help I solved it, just one quick clarification question, why is a(x) -a0 divided by x?

Comment: If you look at the term on the left in the line above it, we have a sum that starts at $n = 1$ of a power series in $x^{n-1}$, so if you multiply it by $x$ to raise that to $x^n$ and then add the $a_0x^0$ term back in, you get the original power series for $A(x)$.